# Scrape multiple pages with the same url using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I have the following code that scrapes some information I need from a website. However, there are **61** pages I need to go through and scrape the same data that requires me to click on the 'Next' button to go to the next page with the `url` remaining the same.

I know it is possible to use `driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()` to go to the next page but I am not sure how to include this in my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://mspotrace.org.my/Sccs_list')
time.sleep(20)

# Get list of elements
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='View on Map']")))

# Loop through element popups and pull details of facilities into DF
pos = 0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['facility_name','other_details'])

for element in elements:
    try: 
        data = []
        element.click()
        time.sleep(10)
        facility_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h4[@class="modal-title"]').text
        other_details = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="modal-body"]').text
        time.sleep(5)
        data.append(facility_name)
        data.append(other_details)
        df.loc[pos] = data
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Close'] > span"))).click() # close popup window
        print("Scraping info for",facility_name,"")
        time.sleep(15)
        pos+=1

    except Exception:
        alert = driver.switch_to.alert
        print("No geo location information")
        alert.accept()
        pass
       
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to your question, "I don't know how I would put it in my code"

Counter iii is used to repeat your existing code 60 times.
I cannot test the entire code, but I tested the loops.

For the sake of simplicity, in the code below I removed the element scraping so I could focus the test on repeating the clicks in the Next button, which is your question.

If you are going to test on your side, ensure you replace

```
print('your stuff would stay here!')
```

with the actual element scraping block that you have in your original code.

Hope it helps!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://mspotrace.org.my/Sccs_list')
time.sleep(20)

# Get list of elements
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='View on Map']")))

# Loop through element popups and pull details of facilities into DF
pos = 0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['facility_name','other_details'])
for iii in range(1,60):
    for element in elements:
        print('your stuff would stay here!')

    #click next
    btnNext = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dTable_next"]/a')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", btnNext)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btnNext)
    time.sleep(5)
    
    #print current df. You may want to store it and print in the end only?
    print(df)

    # Get list of elements again
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='View on Map']")))

    # Resetting vars again
    pos = 0
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['facility_name','other_details'])
```